# Airflow install broken. `table dag_stats already exists`

Tags: configuration, airflow

My Airflow install has stopped working. UI Webserver doesn't come up. I think the problem is related to the following error that appears when I run

`> airflow initdb`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table dag_stats already exists
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE dag_stats (
    dag_id VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, 
    state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    count INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    dirty BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (dag_id, state), 
    CHECK (dirty IN (0, 1))
)

]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can get back to work?

Comment: But the webserver still won't come up. Anyone know how to diagnose that?

Answer (score 13):

I just deleted the database

`> rm ~/airflow/airflow.db`

and initialized a new one with

`> airflow initdb`

which works now.

Comment: Answer is not working for WSL airflow instance. when doing remove automatically new db is getting created.

Comment: I have never used WSL, but I'm curious if employing `airflow resetdb` gives better results.

Comment: actually , it does not work after resetting DB on WSL. I had to shut down  WSL and then deleted content of  ~/airflow  and then started Airflow instance from start with DB init -> create user-> webserver -> scheduler . Then it started running again.

Answer (score 0):

airflow command is changed. For the recent version i.e. 2.8.1, command for init db is "airflow db init"