# Error while initializing database in apache airflow, below is the attached error, Thankyou

Tags: python-3.x, linux, airflow, centos7

##database intialization in apache airflow.
I have installed apache airflow in linux with python 3.8 version. while running airflow commands it showing version name. error occured while initializing database in airflow. explain the error below and solution, thanks

```
/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:3463 SAWarning: relationship 'DagRun.serialized_dag' will copy column serialized_dag.dag_id to column dag_run.dag_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'TaskInstance.dag_run' (copies task_instance.dag_id to dag_run.dag_id), 'DagRun.task_instances' (copies task_instance.dag_id to dag_run.dag_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   The 'overlaps' parameter may be used to remove this warning. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)
    /home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:3463 SAWarning: relationship 'SerializedDagModel.dag_runs' will copy column serialized_dag.dag_id to column dag_run.dag_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'TaskInstance.dag_run' (copies task_instance.dag_id to dag_run.dag_id), 'DagRun.task_instances' (copies task_instance.dag_id to dag_run.dag_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   The 'overlaps' parameter may be used to remove this warning. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)
      ____________       _____________
     ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
    ____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
    ___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
     _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
    [2021-04-29 11:50:40,298] {dagbag.py:448} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
    [2021-04-29 11:50:40,330] {manager.py:727} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
    [2021-04-29 11:50:41,340] {abstract.py:229} ERROR - Failed to add operation for GET /api/v1/connections
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 209, in add_paths
        self.add_operation(path, method)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 173, in add_operation
        pass_context_arg_name=self.pass_context_arg_name
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/operations/__init__.py", line 8, in make_operation
        return spec.operation_cls.from_spec(spec, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py", line 138, in from_spec
        **kwargs
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py", line 89, in __init__
        pass_context_arg_name=pass_context_arg_name
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/operations/abstract.py", line 96, in __init__
        self._resolution = resolver.resolve(self)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 40, in resolve
        return Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id), operation_id)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 66, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
        raise ResolverError(str(e), sys.exc_info())
    connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: columns>
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
        args.func(args)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 89, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/webserver_command.py", line 360, in webserver
        app = cached_app(None)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 135, in cached_app
        app = create_app(config=config, testing=testing)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 120, in create_app
        init_api_connexion(flask_app)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_views.py", line 172, in init_api_connexion
        specification='v1.yaml', base_path=base_path, validate_responses=True, strict_validation=True
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 57, in add_api
        api = super(FlaskApp, self).add_api(specification, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apps/abstract.py", line 156, in add_api
        options=api_options.as_dict())
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 111, in __init__
        self.add_paths()
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 216, in add_paths
        self._handle_add_operation_error(path, method, err.exc_info)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 231, in _handle_add_operation_error
        raise value.with_traceback(traceback)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 61, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
        return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 111, in get_function_from_name
        module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api_connexion/endpoints/connection_endpoint.py", line 26, in <module>
        from airflow.api_connexion.schemas.connection_schema import (
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api_connexion/schemas/connection_schema.py", line 42, in <module>
        class ConnectionSchema(ConnectionCollectionItemSchema):  # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 125, in __new__
        dict_cls=dict_cls,
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 92, in get_declared_fields
        fields.update(mcs.get_auto_fields(fields, converter, opts, dict_cls))
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 106, in get_auto_fields
        for field_name, field in fields.items()
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 108, in <dictcomp>
        and field_name not in opts.exclude
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 28, in create_field
        return converter.field_for(model, column_name, **self.field_kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 179, in field_for
        converted_prop = self.property2field(prop, **kwargs)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 146, in property2field
        field_class = field_class or self._get_field_class_for_property(prop)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 223, in _get_field_class_for_property
        column = prop.columns[0]
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1220, in __getattr__
        return self._fallback_getattr(key)
      File "/home/hduser/apache_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1194, in _fallback_getattr
        raise AttributeError(key)
    AttributeError: columns
```

the above is the error while running airflow initdb

Answer (score 7):

This can be fixed by rolling back the version of SQLAlchemy. Try uninstalling SQLAlchemy and installing an older version of it. I used SQLAlchemy 1.3.20 and was able to get it working.

Comment: this solution saved my day, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I came across this (and many other) problems while trying to implement a dockerized airflow for our data engineering team. I'm not sure what the exact cause was, but somewhere along the line of troubleshooting I think the database got bad data (I had to remove the volume that persisted the psql container's data).

Aside from that, something docker-specific is that some python modules installed during the docker build phase were not accessible due to permission issues (installed modules as one user, ran container as a different user).

Hope this helps. If you find out exactly what the cause of this error is, please let us know!

Comment: Restarting the docker container and re-running `airflow db init` worked. No idea what happened.

Comment: After that I got another error and had to delete the DB (to start from scratch), more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66003438/airflow-install-broken-table-dag-stats-already-exists

Answer (score 4):

If you have `sqlalchemy > 1.4`, this can be fixed by upgrading `marshmallow-sqlalchemy`

> pip install -U marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Comment: As of writing, there are internal conflicts which require `marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.27.0`